# Breaking down numpy code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have been meticulously reading documentation and rereading/running the below code in order to understand exactly what is occurring. There are still gaps in my knowledge though. I wanted to present the code to you, with comments, which signify the gaps in my knowledge that hopefully some of you are willing to fill.

So here are my request friends:
1) Help me fill in gaps in my knowledge 
2) Explain what is going on here step by step in a non-technical and simple format.

```
import numpy
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot

lena = scipy.misc.lena()


''' Generates an artificial range within the framework of the original array (Which is an image)
This artificial range will be paired with another one and used to 'climb'
Through the original array and make changes'''

def get_indices(size):
    arr = numpy.arange(size)
    #This sets every fourth element to False? How?
    return arr % 4 == 0

lena1 = lena.copy()
xindices = get_indices(lena.shape[0])
yindices = get_indices(lena.shape[1])




'''I am unsure of HOW the below code is executing. I know something is being
Set to zero, but what? And how can I verify it?'''

lena[xindices, yindices] = 0

#What does the argument 211 do exactly?
matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(211)
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(lena1)


matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Thanks mates!

Comment: Did you try to understand what `scipy.misc.lena` returns? Where or why did you get stuck?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. The most confusing part for me is "lena[xindices, yindices] = 0"

Comment: `a[i, j]` is just a numpy way of saying for `a[i][j]`, i.e. to index multidimensional arrays. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Some of these things are answered in one of your other questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Python debugger is always useful to step through your code while it is executing. Write the following in any place you choose:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Execution will be stopped and you can inspect any variable, use any defined functions, and advance line by line.

Here you have a commented version of your code. The comment on the function is transformed into a docstring with a doctest that could be executed.

```
import numpy
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot

# Get classic image processing example image, Lena, at 8-bit grayscale
# bit-depth, 512 x 512 size.
lena = scipy.misc.lena()
# lena is now a Numpy array of integers, between 245 and 25, of 512 rows and
# 512 columns.


def get_indices(size):
    """
    Returns each fourth index in a Numpy vector of the passed in size.
    Specifically, return a vector of booleans, where all indices are set to
    False except those of every fourth element. This vector can be used to
    index another Numpy array and select *only* those elements. Example use:

        >>> import numpy as np
        >>> vector = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
        >>> get_indices(vector.size)
        array([ True, False, False, False,  True], ...)

    """
    arr = numpy.arange(size)
    return arr % 4 == 0

# Keep a copy of the original image
lena1 = lena.copy()

# Use the defined function to get every fourth index, first in the x direction,
# then in the y direction
xindices = get_indices(lena.shape[0])
yindices = get_indices(lena.shape[1])


# Set every pixel that equals true in the vectors further up to 0. This
# selects **each fourth pixel on the diagonal** (from up left to bottom right).
lena[xindices, yindices] = 0

# Create a Matplotlib plot, with 2 subplots, and selects the one on the 1st
# colum, 1st row. The layout for all subplots is determined from all calls to
# subplot, i.e. if you later call `subplot(212)` you will get a vertical layout
# in one column and two rows; but if you call `subplot(221)` you will get a
# horizontal layout in two columns and one row.
matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(211)
# Show the unaltered image on the first subplot
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(lena1)
# You could plot the modified original image in the second subplot, and compare
# to the unmodified copy by issuing:
#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(212)
#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(lena)

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```